# convert date in 2015-05-09T09:00:12.123462000 to unix timestamp in hive

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp, to-date

I want to convert the date which is in '2015-05-09T09:00:12.123462000' format to the unix timestamp in hive. The UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-05-09T09:00:12.123462000') doesn't work. I am not sure how i can convert this. I need this to compare two dates in different format. I am converting both the dates to unix timestamp but this fails. can someone please help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input uses the full [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, with a "T" between date and time, and fractional seconds. Hive expects an SQL format *(i.e. with a space between date and time)* as seen in [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) and [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity), with or without fractional seconds, as [stated in the Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-timestamp).

Just apply some very elementary string massaging -- then "cast" the `String` to a Hive [`Timestamp`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-timestamp). And pleeease forget that lame roundtrip to and from UNIX_TIMESTAMP:

```
cast(regexp_replace('2015-05-09T09:00:12.123462000', 'T',' ') as Timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Samson Scharfrichter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39776057/642706) is correct and should be accepted. I'll just add some words about java.time types.

## Converting between String ↔ `java.time.Instant`

The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `java.sql.Timestamp`.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Your input string complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings that represent date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern. You can directly parse your string as an `Instant` object.

Your input string lacks an indication of offset-from-UTC or time zone. If it was intended to be in UTC, append a `Z` for `Zulu` which means UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2015-05-09T09:00:12.123462000" + "Z" );
```

You can generate such a string, merely call `toString`. The default formatter used by `toString` prints the decimal fraction in groups of three digits as needed. In this example the last three digits are zeros so they are omitted.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2015-05-09T09:00:12.123462Z

To make this into SQL-style string expected by Hive, replace the `T` with a SPACE and remove the `Z`.

```
String inputForHive = output.replace( "T" , " " ).replace( "Z" , "" );
```

> 2015-05-09 09:00:12.123462

## Conversion from numbers

Hive also provides for conversions from:

- integer number
  Count of whole seconds from the [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)/Posix [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of beginning of 1970 UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`).
- floating-point number
  Same as above but with a fractional second in up to nanoseconds resolution.

The second one I suggest you avoid. The [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) types such as `float`, `Float`, `double`, and `Double` in Java purposely trade off accuracy for faster execution time. This often results in extraneous digits at the end of your decimal fraction. If you need fractional second, stick with the String type & `Instant` object.

The first one can easily be obtained from an `Instant` by calling the `getEpochSecond` method. Of course this means data loss as this method leaves behind any fractional second.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = instant.getEpochSecond();
```

Going the other direction.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( secondsSinceEpoch );
```

## Comparing

Once you have your `Instant` objects, you can compare with methods such as [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#compareTo-java.time.Instant-), [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#isBefore-java.time.Instant-), [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#isAfter-java.time.Instant-).

```
Boolean happenedBefore = thisInstant.isBefore( thatInstant );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: IMHO this is largely off-topic. Hive interface is SQL (kind of). It's a skin around Java types and Java methods, true; but whoever asks a short question without much context -- like this one -- is not likely to be interested about implementation details of Hive, or what you could do outside of Hive.

Answer (score 0):

If available you can simply use the following syntax

1) check whether what UDFs are available in your hive install?

```
show functions;
```

2) if seen from_unixtime() function then:

```
from_unixtime(your_timestamp_field)
```

This will solve the problem!

Please add comments, if you like my answer!